# GridView fake item

Tags: android, android-gridview

I need to create dashboard using GridView.
One of the items will be an item that, when clicked, will add new item to an adapter array.
I need to create that one item in a way that it will not be added to the adapter array, because i.e all items will be saved to file.

Is there any way that I can add such item without adding it to adapter array of GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your adapter: `ArrayAdapter<(type)> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<(type)>(params)` then create a button (or whatever item you are using to add values to the array) and set an `onClick` where you can do `adapter.add(item)`. If you want that button (for example) to be in your `GridView` but not save it to a file, just have your file saver exclude `position=0` which should be defined in your `Adapter` class.